# JMeter Generate Summary Results shows incorrect values

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have built a simple Test Plan which executes 20 HTTP requests using one thread. It runs one iteration. The result file (.jtl) shows that it executed 20 requests. However, the JMeter Generate Summary Results seems incorrect.  The Generate Summary Results shows 30 in 49 seconds. Is this a JMeter Bug or am I reading this incorrectly?

```
summary +      6 in     7s =    0.9/s Avg:   817 Min:     4 Max:  4307 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
summary =     20 in  47.4s =    0.4/s Avg:  1444 Min:     4 Max:  9160 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Generate Summary Results =     30 in    49s =    0.6/s Avg:  1587 Min:     4 Max:  9160 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary =     20 in    48s =    0.4/s Avg:  1444 Min:     4 Max:  9160 Err:     0 (0.00%)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the JTL file is written by buffers to improve performances.

So it is regular that summary show a different number as it is based on the real status while JTL may not be yet fully written.

Have a look at this property by changing it:

> # AutoFlush on each line written in XML or CSV output
>   # Setting this to true will result in less test results data loss in >case of Crash
>   # but with impact on performances, particularly for intensive tests (low or no pauses)
>   # Since JMeter 2.10, this is false by default
>   jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true